# exclusions not working in my azure search service indexer

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have this indexer

[image]

Where I want to exclude these extension files but when I use it in my intranet I see this

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Are your files stored with the extension as part of the file name in your data source? This check only works if they are.

Comment: Also, are you certain you had this setting already in place when those documents got indexed? The setting affects what documents go through the indexing process, but if a document is already in the index, changing it after the fact won't remove it.

Comment: @CareyHalton Yes, of course, the files are the work files that I upload to Azure from my LAN and they upload with the full name and extension

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I have reset the indexer and have executed it several times since I am adding files periodically and I never get these excursions to take effect

Comment: Resetting the indexer won't cause documents to be deleted from the index. So if these documents were indexed prior to adding the configuration to exclude their extensions, you will need to delete them from the index manually if you want them to no longer appear. Or just delete and recreate the index entirely. They should stop being indexed for future indexer runs now that you have the config, but the indexer won't delete them if they are already there, even after a reset.